# How can a program remove the menu in Control-Alt-Delete (Secure desktop) in Windows?

Tags: windows, software

In reference to another [post about the Respondus Lockdown Browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248147/how-can-a-non-admin-program-cover-your-entire-screen-with-a-window), I was wondering how can a program edit and remove parts of the "Secure Desktop" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> menu in Windows, as well as disable the power button at the bottom right?

Is this safe?

This is what happens when trying to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> with Respondus Lockdown Browser running in the background:

[image: Windows Lockscreen while running Respondus Lockdown Browser in the background]

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly hardening configurations done from [registry keys](https://appuals.com/remove-options-from-the-ctrl-alt-del-screen-in-windows-10/), they can be configured from the Local Group Policies, GPO or directly from regedit. They key is located here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Note that the following path is targeting the current user (HKCU), you can also target at the computer level (HKLM).

From there, you can create/modify multiple strings values and disable or turn them on (set to 0 or 1) :

```
DisableLockWorkstation
HideFastUserSwitching
NoLogoff
DisableChangePassword
DisableTaskMgr
```

Comment: is it possible to bypass that lockdown , i mean tricking the programming into thinking that it successfully made that modification without it actually working? i mean like change that path to a new one so when the program modifies the old one ... nothing actually happen as the real key is in the new path ... what do you think ?